# Moving a 'UITabBarController with UINavigationController' iPhone app to 'UITabBarController with UISplitView' on iPad

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app where the appDelegate has a UITabBarController.  Each of the tabs has a navigation controller which I currently use to push a single detail view onto the stack in each tab.  I am hoping to replace my navigation controller on each of the tabs with a splitViewController.  I use the Interface builder to provide the UINavigationController for each tab.  I am having trouble loading a nib for each tab that has a UISplitViewController in it.  I am getting an instance of the UITableViewController class displaying on the screen, but I am not getting the UISplitviewController or the Popover or the detail view etc.  These classes are all working in a standalone app, but I am not able to get them into each of the tabs in one app.  Although I am currently using the Interface Builder I am open to doing this programmatically. If someone has suggestions, or an example small project of a Tab based app with individual split views in the tabs I would appreciate it very much.  (As this is my first question I am not sure how much code or other pictures from IB would be helpful for me to post.  If you need further detail please let me know and I would gladly amend this post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html)

"The split view controller’s view should always be installed as the root view of your application window. You should never present a split view inside of a navigation or tab bar interface."

Moving on...

Answer (score 0):

Not only shouldn't you -- if you do so, an error is thrown when you run. It's impossible.